# Issue in building opencv .a and .so for android with my module

Tags: android, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and also to this group. Currently I am working on some project on android phone ICS  that  requires OpenCV libs.
My module code is written in C and in that code I want to call some OpenCV lib function.
Just to start with , I have downloaded the OpenCV-2.4.0 for android platform.

- Steps I have taken so far:

  1. Copied the .a and .so file into my module folder from \OpenCV-2.4.0-android-bin.tar\OpenCV-2.4.0-android-bin\OpenCV-2.4.0\libs\armeabi-v7a
  2. Copied .h file into my module folder from \OpenCV-2.4.0-android-bin.tar\OpenCV-2.4.0-android-bin\OpenCV-2.4.0\include
  3. Add .h ,.a and .so path in my module's android.mk file.
  4. Execute build.

Now I am getting linking errors in libopencv_core.a
When I removed libopencv_core.a from .mk file, build was success.
I think libopencv_core.a has a dependency on other lib for these functions (gzopen, gzclose etc)

```
prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/jaguark/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libopencv_core_intermediates/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): in function icvPuts(CvFileStorage*, char const*):persistence.cpp(.text._ZL7icvPutsP13CvFileStoragePKc+0x20): error: undefined reference to 'gzputs'
prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/jaguark/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libopencv_core_intermediates/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): in function icvGets(CvFileStorage*, char*, int):persistence.cpp(.text._ZL7icvGetsP13CvFileStoragePci+0x26): error: undefined reference to 'gzgets'
prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/jaguark/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libopencv_core_intermediates/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): in function icvXMLSkipSpaces(CvFileStorage*, char*, int):persistence.cpp(.text._ZL16icvXMLSkipSpacesP13CvFileStoragePci+0x1e2): error: undefined reference to 'gzgets'
prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/jaguark/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libopencv_core_intermediates/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): in function icvXMLSkipSpaces(CvFileStorage*, char*, int):persistence.cpp(.text._ZL16icvXMLSkipSpacesP13CvFileStoragePci+0x208): error: undefined reference to 'gzeof'
prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/jaguark/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libopencv_core_intermediates/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): in function icvXMLSkipSpaces(CvFileStorage*, char*, int):persistence.cpp(.text._ZL16icvXMLSkipSpacesP13CvFileStoragePci+0x33c): error: undefined reference to 'gzeof'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can follow these [tutorials](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html) about how to use OpenCV for an android project and [NDK-build](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html). At the begining it is a bit tricky. I also had problems with a library that after each compilation, dissapeared, and I had to include again and again each time.